# How to let the compiler know where am I import

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I want to put current CPU usage to the CPU variable like this:

```
import * as os from 'os';
cpu = os.cpus();
```

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoUTs.png)

But it causes this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/Controllers/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'F:\Creeper Studio Products\MinecraftServerWebConsole\src\app\Controllers'
```

And the application is failed to compile.

I think maybe the compiler doesn't know where the "os" is.

Comment: Please include code as text, not as an image. See [mcve], [ask], and [a longer explanation why images for code don't work](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that a browser (and, as an extension, an Angular app) has access to hardware info, so it simply won't work.

So while it's true that webpack doesn't know what `'os'` is supposed to mean (you don't have an `"os"` entry in your `package.json`, do you?), it's beside the problem.

Comment: Actually, I'm developing an Angular application with Electron. So I need to use Electron API to tell Angular app the system information or the things that the browser can't get.